# How to group data per field key?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

For example, I run aggregation query within the list which has:

```
[
    { "vector": { "age": 31, "location" : "SF" }},
    { "vector": { "age": 21, "location" : "NY" }}
]
```

and I would like to group them and get the result like

```
{
  "age": [31, 21],
   "location": ["SF", NY]
}
```

Please tell me how to get such as result with query operators.

Comment: Should `age` and `location` be in specific order within array?

Comment: @dikesh No, it is not important, we can sort them out if values are continuousm e.g. numerical. I'm thinking about $concat...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` command and `group by NULL` to push all elements to respective array.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {
        $group : {
            _id : null,
            age : {$push : "$vector.age"},
            location: {$push : "$vector.location"}
        }
    }
])
```

Following will be output:

```
{ "_id" : null, "age" : [ 31, 21 ], "location" : [ "SF", "NY" ] }
```

Comment: Thanks! This should be right the answer, cause it works as I expect :)